# Copy files to directory if they are not in another directory

Tags: linux, command-line

I have four files `file1, file2, file3, file4`.

A directory `/All` contains all four files, a directory `/A` contains `file1, file2`. Now I want to copy the rest `file3, file4` to another directory `/B`. How can I do this in the command line?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Could you maybe show us the directory structure so that we can get a better understanding? You can use the `tree` command for this.

Comment: Look at `rsync` it supports local copy

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./All/ -type f -exec bash -c '[ ! -e "./A/$(basename "$0")" ] && cp "$0" ./B/' '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution (in `bash`) will support spaces in filenames if you need, although not subdirectories.

```
diff <(\ls /A) <(\ls /All) | egrep '^> ' | cut -b 3- | xargs -d'\n' -I {}  cp "/All/{}" "/B/{}"
```